# subprocess.py returning non zero ./test not being created

Tags: python, c++

So i'm getting a Traceback(most recent call) which i believe means my program is returning a non zero.  When i call

```
subprocess.run(["./test.o"], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #stderr=subprocess.PIPE
```

there is no .out to execute.

But when i run

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o mainTest -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```

it works perfectly fine so shouldn't be returning a non zero.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import os
import subprocess
import sys  
print (sys.version)

#print(fileList) 
with open("reactphysics3d-master/src/react3d.txt", "r") as files:
file_list = [line.strip() for line in files]

p = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/g++", "-Wall"] + file_list + ["-lglut", 
"-lGLU", "-lGL", "-std=c++11", "-o", "test.o", 'main.cpp'],  
stderr=subprocess.PIPE) #stdout=subprocess.PIPE,

subprocess.run(["./test.o"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
#stderr=subprocess.PIPE
```

Is it something to do with the files I'm including, it seems to be giving linking errors when i try to create a collision world with react physics 3d. But that shouldn't be cause the files are linked first and then compiled so i would need to gather all the .cpp which is the purpose of this shell and .py

Comment: ./Makefile is showing showing all the files can't be found, damn i must have changed some paths or something in the actual files. Is it best to just delete the library and start again as in redo cmake?

Comment: It seems the files in ./Makefile are looking for .o and .s of my .cpp files.